# MongoDB lte doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

Hi I'm trying to implant the mongodb lte function
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/

but it doesn't seem to work :s
my route :

```
app.route('/sign/:projectId/:startWeek/:endWeek')
    .post(sign.readExport);
```

Controller:

```
exports.readExport = function(req, res) {
    Sign.find()
        .where('projectId').equals(req.params.projectId)
        .where('startWeek').gte(req.params.startWeek).lte(req.params.endWeek)
        .sort('-created')
        .exec(function(err, sign) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                });
            } else {
                res.jsonp(sign);
            }
        });
};
```

got a db object with startWeek":"9"

using postman I get these results

```
http://localhost:3000/sign/658/8/8
//respons null as it should

http://localhost:3000/sign/658/8/9
//respons my object as it should

http://localhost:3000/sign/658/8/10
http://localhost:3000/sign/658/8/11
http://localhost:3000/sign/658/8/12...
//respons null should respons my object ??
```

What did I do wrong ? :)

Comment: @JohnnyHK  are yea ofc. got it to work now !! just changed db value from string to number thx :p  you can post it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The sorting of numeric strings is tripping you up. You need to change the `startWeek` values in your docs to be numbers instead of strings.

`'10' < '9'`, but `10 > 9`.